# Fix ansible-playbook error: "ERROR! the role 'zzet.rbenv' was not found in ..."

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

I am running ansible like so:

```bash
ansible-playbook -i hosts setup_my_host_name.yml
```

I am getting the error:

```
ERROR! the role 'zzet.rbenv' was not found in /Users/user_name/repo_name/roles:/Users/user_name/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/Users/user_name/repo_name

The error appears to be in '/Users/user_name/repo_name/setup_my_host_name.yml': line 83, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
    - role: zzet.rbenv
      ^ here
```

The relevant lines from the yml file are:

```yml
  roles:
    - role: zzet.rbenv
```

How can I fix the error? Is there anything missing in my ansible installation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible, role not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873635/ansible-role-not-found-error)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε: Thank you, it is similar, so I added this link to my answer! However, both my question **and** the solution in my answer are simpler, and it worked for me.

Comment: A solution that do work for one person is not what StackOverflow Is thriving as a Q&A, otherwise it would be flooded with tons of similar questions to do the exact same to install package Z instead of package Y. Plus, the dupe actual raises the good way to do it in an overall manner: via a requirements file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the missing role:

```
ansible-galaxy install zzet.rbenv
```

Output:

```
Starting galaxy role install process
- downloading role 'rbenv', owned by zzet
- downloading role from https://github.com/zzet/rbenv/archive/3.6.0.tar.gz
- extracting zzet.rbenv to /Users/user_name/.ansible/roles/zzet.rbenv
- zzet.rbenv (3.6.0) was installed successfully
```

**REFERENCES:**

- [Ansible Playbooks vs Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32101001/967621)
- Installing roles from Galaxy: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#installing-roles-from-galaxy

**SEE ALSO:**

- CodeGnome/centos7-lapp-qa: Minimalist LAPP stack environment for integration testing with Cucumber and Capybara: https://github.com/CodeGnome/centos7-lapp-qa
- [Ansible playbook ERROR! the role 'Juniper.junos' was not found in /home/](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68995393/967621)
- [Ansible not seeing host list or role](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58101122/967621)
- [Ansible, role not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39873635/967621)